# Sending a message to the parent window in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, ipc, modal-window

I have a rendering process open a modal window

```
import { remote } from 'electron';

let currentWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow();
let modalWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:800, heigh:500, parent:currentWindow});
modalWindow.loadURL('views/second.html');
```

How can I pass a message **from** the `modalWindow` back to its parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **ipc** communication.

In the Main process:

```
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
   //manage data
})
```

And in your modalWindow:

```
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', message)
```

[ipcMain doc](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md)

[ipcRenderer doc](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md)